# PySimpleGUI : Add border to a column

Tags: pysimplegui

Is there a way to add a border to a column?
I searched online but the only thing i could find was how to add a border to an input.
Is there a way to it with Columns?

Comment: Why not use `sg.Frame` with null string as first argument `title` ?

Comment: True i could do that

Comment: @JasonYang with the frame i can t change the size unless i put somethin in the frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option to set border of `sg.Column`, maybe you can use `sg.Frame`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Frame(
        '',
        [
            [sg.Text(f'Line {i}')] for i in range(5)
        ],
        key='COL',
        border_width=1,
    )],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

or use `sg.Column` with tkinter code to set the border,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Column(
        [
            [sg.Text(f'Line {i}')] for i in range(5)
        ],
        key='COL',
    )],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
window['COL'].Widget.configure(borderwidth=1, relief=sg.DEFAULT_FRAME_RELIEF)
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```